# Android studio .so file dlopen failed:, but it search on the computer not the phone

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am triing to make an app on api level 23 with .so file. It works great on under api level 23. But on 23 i have got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "D:\projects2\Trunc\Viwe\dev-android\studioProject\app\.externalNativeBuild\ndkBuild\allDebug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/someLibrary.so" not found
```

here is my gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
                }
            }
}
externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path file("../../cECG_native/Android.mk") //this is for get the file from an outter library
        }
    }
```

the Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := something
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := someLibrary.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := somethingUtil
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := something
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And i get the error when try to load the somethingUtil:

```
System.loadLibrary("something"); //this works
System.loadLibrary("somethingUtil"); //this line i get error
```

Can you help me how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you build somethungUtil? Does UnsatisfiedLinkError show its name, or some other (third) name?

Comment: @AlexCohn what do you mean: "How do you build somethungUtil?"

Comment: well, your somethingUtil looks empty, that's why I asked. Actually, I would suggest to run `ndk-build APP_ABI="armeabi-v7a armeabi" -B V=1` manually, and check if the problem is with gradle integration or within NDK.